# Laravel Sail Docker - During inheritance of ArrayAccess

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

Windows 11, Laravel v8.49.0, Docker with WSL 2 using Ubuntu-20.04. (Tried with PHP 7.4.x, 8.0.x and 8.1.x).

Problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with Ar
rayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/C
ollections/Collection.php:1459
```

Setup:

- Run `bash ./vendor/bin/sail up`
- mysql gets started
- PHP fatal error shows up
- Docker retries, same output comes out

I couldn't find related issues to be honest, and decided to post here. I've added `sail` into an existing project, and I cannot do a fresh install, as the project is beyond that stage.

Complete stacktrace:

```
laravel.test_1  | Stack trace:
laravel.test_1  | #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
laravel.test_1  | #1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('...')
laravel.test_1  | #2 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
laravel.test_1  | #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()

laravel.test_1  | #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): collect()
laravel.test_1  | #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
laravel.test_1  | #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
laravel.test_1  | #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
laravel.test_1  | #8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
laravel.test_1  | #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
laravel.test_1  | #10 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
laravel.test_1  | #11 {main} in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php on line 13
laravel.test_1  | PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Collection" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php:15
laravel.test_1  | Stack trace:
laravel.test_1  | #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(24): collect()
laravel.test_1  | #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(44): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->closureParameterTypes()
laravel.test_1  | #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/ReportableHandler.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->firstClosureParamete
rType()
laravel.test_1  | #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(234): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->handles()
laravel.test_1  | #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(88): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report()
laravel.test_1  | #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException()
laravel.test_1  | #6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
laravel.test_1  | #7 {main}
```

Comment: I've just checked XAMPP, it uses V8.0.8. My window's PHP is V8.1.0, the docker is now using PHP 8.1.0. The issue still persists. I think downgrading that much would ruin the whole setup, as I'm using Laravel v8. It's really confusing.

Comment: Okay, the problem is actually bigger than that. Fixing one issue shows up another one. There's a conflicting PHP version, but I cannot find where it lays. The new error `Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with Array
Access::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed`

Comment: I deleted some of these comments because it's too much useless stuff ... lol

Comment: Have you tried updating everything with composer, I would make a backup but that could take care of it.  Composer is there to help with these very kinds of issues.  It's beyond the scope of SO to explain it and there are many tutorials.

I've never used Docker myself..

Comment: Hmm, the issue is more related to Docker more than Laravel.

Comment: I'm not sure it has more to do with Docker, the use of Docker just adds more variables. How are you installing your dependencies? For example, if using the official composer docker image, it's most likely running in PHP 8 and will install dependencies based on that regardless of the PHP version set for your runtime container (unless you set the platform in the composer.json).

Comment: Running XAMPP and browsing the project outputs no issues. This stacktrace only pops up when trying to use `sail up` command. Docker was installed normally, then applied the Ubuntu image (version in OP), then ran the `sail up` command.

Comment: issue solved by downgrading php

Comment: any other solution?
my project working with php7.4 and 8 but with 8.1 I have same issue

Comment: I had to reinstall everything full and made it worked. Eventually, it wasn't worth the hassle for me. Reinstall the drivers from Microsoft, check the verified PHP version on your project and for docker, it should be identical.